# What is the difference between `rename_column` in self.up v self.down (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rails-migrations

What is the difference between `rename_column` in `self.up` v `self.down`?

I have a migration file that looks like below:

```
def self.up
  rename_column :posts, :title, :subject
end

def self.down
  rename_column :posts, :subject, :title
end
```

Until now I've only seen `def change` in migration files. Not `self.up` and `self.down`.

I can see how this would make sense if one was `remove_column` and one was `add_column` - to simulate a `rename_column`, with the added benefit of being able to alter the datatype, etc.

But I don't see why `rename` would be required twice. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rename_column` is used in both `up` and `down` because there's no need to change any of the column details other than the name. Both `title` and `subject` are relatively short, text-based values. If you dropped a column and added a new one, you'd just be using the same datatype and other attributes. Renaming a column is simply more expedient in this case.

Just because you're changing a column doesn't imply that you have to change everything about it.